# Resharper dosn't recognize the correct ViewModel Type

Tags: c#, wpf, resharper

We are using Resharper and of course we want to take advantage of Resharper's xaml intellisense.

Our View's Data Context are bound to a `CurrentViewmodel` property of type `ViewModelBase`. At runtime this Property is set with a View model inheritating from `ViewModelBase`.

I already added those lines in the View model to set the correct Type:

```
xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:PQS.ViewModel.Report"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vms:ReportFilterViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
```

But Resharper still keeps looking in `ViewModelbase` for the Properties.

What else can i try?

Some more Code:

Setting the DataContext:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="ReportMainViewModel.CurrentVm"  Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Binding Something (Products is a Property on ReportFilterViewmodel, r# keeps looking for it in ViewModelBase):

```
<ListBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Products.View}" Background="White" DisplayMemberPath="Name.ActualTranslation">
                    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you please provide larger code example (with binding expression itself)? R# should handle the design-time attributes you've provide.

Comment: Please see the new code parts i added.

Comment: Are you setting both the DesignInstance and the real DataContext in xaml as provided? ReSharper is probably looking at the explicit DataContext being set and not the DesignInstance then.

Comment: Yes I do, i just checked if i remove the UserControl.DataContext  part it works. But how to bind my DataContext now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R# can't statically find concrete view model type that will be available in runtime, so you need to annotate data context type manually like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class MainWindow {
  public MainWindow() {
    Current = new ConcreteViewModel {
      Products = {
        new Product(),
        new Product()
      }
    };

    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public ViewModelBase Current { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelBase { }
public class ConcreteViewModel : ViewModelBase {
  public ConcreteViewModel() {
    Products = new List<Product>();
  }

  public List<Product> Products { get; private set; }
}

public class Product {
  public string ProductName { get { return "Name1"; } }
}
```

And XAML part:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" x:Name="MainWin"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:global="clr-namespace:" mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=Current}">
  <!-- here the type of data context is ViewModelBase -->
  <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance global:ConcreteViewModel}">
    <!-- and here is ConcreteViewModel -->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Or like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" x:Name="MainWin"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:global="clr-namespace:"
        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=Current}">
  <Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(global:ConcreteViewModel.Products)}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```